# SQL Inner Join and nearest row to date

Tags: sql

I don't get it. I changed some of the code. In the WPLEVENT Table are a lot of Events per person. In the Persab-Table are the Persons with their History. Now I need the from the Persab Table just that row which matches the persab.gltab Date nearest to the WPLEVENT.vdat Date. So all rows from the WPLEVENT, but just the one matching row from the PERSAB-Table.

```
SELECT 
      persab.name, 
      persab.vorname, 
      vdat, 
      eventstart, 
      persab.rc1,
      persab.rc2
    FROM wplevent
    INNER JOIN 
      persab ON WPLEVENT.PersID = persab.PRIMKEY
    INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT TOP 1 persab.rc1
      FROM PERSAB 
      WHERE persab.gltab <= getdate() --/ Should be wplevent.vdat instead of getdate()
      ) NewTable ON wplevent.persid = persab.primkey
    WHERE 
      persid ='100458'
    ORDER BY vdat DESC
```

Comment: Format properly!  No one is going to read that.

Comment: Also, which dbms is this?

Comment: Here's a good info of how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The syntax of `MAX` is `MAX(expression)` but also you will need `GROUP BY` in the inner query to use MAX when you have the second column that is not aggregated.

Comment: what column you want to select the max

Comment: If you need help, take some time to make your question clear and your code readable.

Comment: You are right. I was to busy. I'll take more time for the next question...

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the `MAX()` function with the proper syntax by supplying an expression like `MAX(persab.rc1)`. Also need to use `GROUP BY` for the second column `rc2` in the subquery (although it looks like you do not need it). Finally you are missing the `ON` clause for the final `INNER JOIN`. I can update the answer to fix the query if you provide that information.

```
SELECT        
      Z1PERS.NAME
    , Z1PERS.VORNAME
    , WPLEVENT.VDat
    , WPLEVENT.EventStart
    , WPLEVENT.EventStop
    , WPLEVENT.PEPGROUP
    , Z1SGRP.TXXT
    , PERSAB.GLTAB
    , Z1PERS.PRIMKEY AS Expr1
    , PERSAB.PRIMKEY
FROM 
    Z1PERS 
INNER JOIN
    WPLEVENT ON Z1PERS.PRIMKEY = WPLEVENT.PersID 
INNER JOIN                         
    Z1SGRP ON WPLEVENT.PEPGROUP = Z1SGRP.GRUPPE 
INNER JOIN
    (
     SELECT MAX(Persab.rc1)  --Fixed MAX expression
          , persab.rc2
     FROM   
            persab
     GROUP BY
            persab.rc2       --Need to group on rc2 if you want that column in the query otherwise remove this AND the rc2 column from select list
     WHERE
            WPLEVENT.PersID = PERSAB.PRIMKEY 
            AND WPLEVENT.VDat <= PERSAB.GLTAB
    )  --Missing ON clause for the INNER JOIN here
WHERE z1pers.vorname = 'henning'
```

Comment: This way I get a syntax-error near the WHERE Keyword ...?!

Comment: I changed my entry in the first post. I hope it's clear what I am looking for. Thanks for help again...

Comment: Well, you have the same query without any of the fixes I added. There are 3 problems. 1) `MAX(column)` is the syntax for MAX 2) If you use MAX with only one column all the others in the SELECT need to be in GROUP BY `persab.rc2` in this case and 3) You are still missing the `ON` clause for that last join. See the comments I put in the query.

Comment: Well that's like a completely different query! By the way if you put four spaces before the line it formats as code so you don't have do each line individually with the tags.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried another solution. May be the description helps out, to understand what is my goal.